# execCommand insertHtml, outer div not inserted why?

Tags: javascript

Why is the DIV not inserted but only the IMG ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '#insertImage', function(){

        /*
        Why is the DIV not inserted ?
        */
         var item = "<div class='resizable'><img src='http://www.rockiesventureclub.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/flower-icon.png'></div>";
         document.execCommand('insertHTML', false,item);


    })
});
```

see:
http://jsfiddle.net/daslicht/gU2jP/#base

Comment: What browser are you using? When I use the inspector in Chrome, I can see the div added in the fiddle ([once its updated to include the div](http://jsfiddle.net/gU2jP/12/)).

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it with jQuery since you already use it??

http://jsfiddle.net/gU2jP/5/

```
var _$div = $('<div>'),
    _$img = $("<img class='resizeable' id='myImg' src='http://imperavi.com/img/library.jpg' />");

_$div.append(_$img);
$('body').append(_$div);
```

Comment: how do I add the image at the current cursor in the content editable div ?

Answer (score 0):

**The background of the Question was the following:**

I just like to be able to make the added Image Float Left or Right.
Since jQueryUI automatically adds a wrapper-div around each resizeable item I thought that I need to add it somehow manually in order to assign a id to it.

doug65536 on Freenode helped me to create this solution without the need to create an additionally div manually:

We also discovered that the Fiddle wont work properly in safari

```
$(document).on('click', '#insertImage', function () {

    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false,
        "<img class='resizeable' id='myImg' src='http://imperavi.com/img/library.jpg'>");


    $(".resizeable").resizable({
        aspectRatio: true
    }); //just a try here

    $('#myImg').parent().css({
        'float':'left',
        'margin':'15px'                     
    });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daslicht/6cGbQ/

Thank you very Much !